# What is the nature of the Nuclear Family?

Tags: character, titans

I know a little about *Nuclear Family* from *Justice League Action* etc but in *Titans* I am confused about the nature of the Nuclear Family. In comics and cartoons, it's a family of robots with different nuclear-related powers.

But in Titans, I am not sure even if they are robots or humans as for *nuclear stepdad* we see them doing some crazy visual experiment on him for a small glimpse. So is there any indication what exactly they are? From in or out of universe from the show's context.

Comment: I assume you haven't finished all the available episodes so far. So I advice you to watch the missing episodes as it becomes clearer with time

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I have seen all and it was not fully clear to me

Answer (score 2):

As I understood it from the series alone - no knowledge from other resources - they are normal humans, which at first are brain washed (just like the organisation tries with Dick). After they are "fully cooked", they obey the orders from the organisation.

Their powers seem to only be coming from the serum they inject them with in one of the earlier episodes. Though it was never explained what exactly that serum is.